# Text in the table are not justifying in a specific cell

Tags: tables, tabularx

One of the tables in the document is giving me hard time. I added the following MWE, the problem is in the second column last cell and the 3rd column. Although I used "X", however, the problem still persists.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}      
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts           
\usepackage[ruled,longend,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetArgSty{textup}
\SetKwBlock{Loop}{Loop}{end}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.39}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\label{} %cXXX  {\linewidth} 
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {|c|p{4cm}| p{5cm}|X|}
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Ref.(s)}& \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Method(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Contribution(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Remark(s)}
          
%&      &PV & ESS &         &Selling &  Buying &Transactions &   & p{6.5cm}
\\
\hline
[11], [12]& \lipsum[1][1-2]  & QoS
guarantees, peak shaving and efficient resource allocation &\multirow[t]{3}{6.5cm}{{\lipsum[1][1-12] }} \\ \cline{1-3} %\cline{4-5}
%\hline

[13], [14]
&\lipsum[1][1-2]  & \lipsum[1][1-3] &  \\ \cline{1-3}


[15], [16] & \lipsum[1][1-2] 
& \lipsum[1][1]  &    \\\cline{1-3}
%\hline
[17], [18]& \lipsum[1][1-2] & \lipsum[1][1]  &   \\ \hline

\textit{Our work}&\lipsum[1][1] &\multirow[t]{3}{5cm}{{\lipsum[1][1-6] }} &\multirow[t]{5}{7cm}{{\lipsum[1][1-8]}}   \\
 &&& \\
 &&& \\
 &&& \\
  &&& \\
   &&& \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the problem that they're not fully justified? I think you could just wrap the contents of those cells in `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{...}`. I would also change the widths given for the `\multirow` cells to the special value `=` which makes them the natural width for the column. Probably there are "cleaner" solutions with the tabularray package.

Comment: Thanks, @frabjous, I loved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize%
                       \hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.39}
\caption{With \texttt{tabularx}}
\label{tab:?} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l | Y{0.9} | Y{0.9} | Y{1.2}| }
    \hline
Ref.(s) 
    & Method(s) 
        & Contribution(s) 
            & Remark(s) \\
%
    \hline
[11], [12]
    & \lipsum[1][1-2]  
        & QoS guarantees, peak shaving and efficient resource allocation
            & \multirow{4}{=}{\lipsum[1][1-12]}        \\ 
    \cline{1-3}
[13], [14]
    &   \lipsum[1][1-2]
        &   \lipsum[1][1-3]
            &                                       \\
    \cline{1-3}
[15], [16]
    &\lipsum[1][1-2]
        & \lipsum[1][1-3]
            &                                       \\
    \cline{1-3}
[17], [18]
    & \lipsum[1][1-2] 
        & \lipsum[1][1]  
            &                                       \\
    \hline
\textit{Our work}
    &   \lipsum[1][1] 
        &   \lipsum[1][1-6]
            &   \lipsum[1][1-8]                     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}


    \begin{table*}
\caption{With \texttt{tabularray}}
\label{tab:??}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l] X[0.9, j]  X[0.9, j] X[1.2, j]},
              colsep = 3pt,
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}
             }
Ref.(s)
    &   Method(s)
        &   Contribution(s)
            &   Remark(s)                           \\
%
{[11], [12]}
    &   \lipsum[1][1-2]
        &   QoS guarantees, peak shaving and efficient resource allocation
            &   \SetCell[r=4]{h}  \lipsum[1][1-12]  \\
{[13], [14]}
    &   \lipsum[1][1-2]
        &   \lipsum[1][1-3]
            &                                       \\
{[15], [16]}
    & \lipsum[1][1-2]
        & \lipsum[1][1-3]
            &                                       \\
{[17], [18]}
    &   \lipsum[1][1-2]
        &   \lipsum[1][1]
            &                                       \\
\textit{Our work}
    &   \lipsum[1][1]
        &   \lipsum[1][1-6]
            &   \lipsum[1][1-8]   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, however, two issues, the first thing is with "tblr " and its packages, the compiler gave an error until I removed it, however, in the second MWE, last  row line(5th row) overlapped with the previous row (4th) text.

Comment: Ar you use Overleaf? It still not support new `tabularray` version. If you have local LaTeX installation, than probably need to install it manually. Regarding `tabularx` it works as is shown in answer. No errors, no warnings no bad boxes (overlap). You probably  change my answer )have longer content in multirow cell, but this unknow to us. BTW, `tabularray manage such cases without any problems or special care . Be aware, that using `multirow` you should consider number of lines in adjacent columns (in your case 13).